# Do something after service finishes on Spring webflux Webfilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a class that implements Webfilter and some endpoints implemented with annotated spring webflux.

I'm able to intercept the request with the filter function:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();

//Do some stuff with the request

return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
}
```

Then the controller is executed, and then I want to do some other stuff after the controller gets executed on every single service I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can chain on things:

```
return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange).then( ... );
```

Comment: I didn't try `then`, but I did try `doOnFinish` and other but only `finally` worked.